# Page redirecting depending on Role using Spring security and Thymeleaf - Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am working on my project with Spring security and Thymeleaf. I have basic Spring Security integration.

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
      public void configureGlobal (AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
      {
        auth
          .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource);
      }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
              .antMatchers("/classesTable").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")

                .and()
            .httpBasic();
      } 
}
```

**SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java**

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer
{
    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer(){
        super(SecurityConfig.class);
    }

}
```

In my project I have three roles: student, professor and admin.
What I would like to achieve is when my student logs in that he is redirected to page indexUser.html. When my professor logs in he is redirected to indexProfesor.html and when admin does he lands on indexAdmin.html page.

I had in mind something like this

```
if(role.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")){
      //redirect from here to indexAdmin.html

    }else if(role.contains("ROLE_USER")) {
        //redirect to indexUser.html
    }else
        //redirect to indexProfesor.html
}
```

But I don't have picture how whole controller should look like.

Have my homeContorller that looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage(Model model) {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Also I added this code to my index.html

```
<span sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
<span sec:authentication="name"></span>
| Roles: <span sec:authentication="principal.authorities"></span> |
```

So I am familiar with role that my logged user has. 
Here is also code for my login.html

```
<form  th:action="@{/login}" method="post" class="l-form">
  <input type="text" name="username"/>
  <input type="password" name="password"/>
  <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" 
   th:value="${_csrf.token}" />

   <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have found solution that works for me.

I added `http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/success", true)` to my *SpringConfig* file.

So it looks like this

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
              .antMatchers("/classesTable").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/success", true)
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
      }
```

Then I made new method in *HomeController* called *loginPageRedirect*

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage(Model model) {
        return "login";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/success")
    public void loginPageRedirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        
        String role =  authResult.getAuthorities().toString();
        
        if(role.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")){
         response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(request.getContextPath() + "/indexAdmin"));                            
         }
         else if(role.contains("ROLE_USER")) {
             response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(request.getContextPath() + "/indexUser"));
         }
    }

}
```

Hope it helps someone with same issue.

Comment: If our answer helps you then you can upvote the answers. Also, You can accept which helps you more. And this is the way to recognize others help. Thank You

Comment: @sunkuet02 Thanks for that note mate!

Answer (score 2):

**First Way**

- You can change your controller method as :

  ```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String loginPage(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
      if(request.isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN") {
           // redirect to indexAdmin.html page
      } else if(request.isUserInRole("ROLE_USER") {
           // redirect indexUser.html page
      } else {
           // redirect to indexProfesor.html page
      }
  }
  ```

  Spring MVC will automatically inject few `HttpServletRequest` properties in `request` parameter, using this you can be benefited.

**Another way**

- You can change your controller method as:

  ```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String loginPage(Model model, Authentication authentication) {
      if(authentication.getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"))) {
          // redirect to indexAdmin.html page
      } else if(authentication.getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"))) {
          // redirect indexUser.html page
      } else {
          // redirect to indexProfesor.html page
      }
  }
  ```

  Here, Spring MVC will automatically inject the `Authentication` properties to `authentication` object.

Comment: I am already familiar with role that my user has. Check my code update. I am trying to redirect him to different page based on role that he has. @sunkuet02

Comment: I just wrote comment on other answer that I got...  _I think I need to make separate controller with mapping for example "/successLogin" and then put logic that you wrote above in it. If I put it like this with mapping "/login" it never takes me to my login page. Do you have any idea of how to do that?_

Comment: @dome, Is there any `login.jsp` page  ?

Comment: You can write `return "redirect:login.html";`  as return statement in `/login` controller method. If it doesn't work, then try without `.html`

Answer (score 2):

You can expose in your controller method the `HttpServletRequest` parameter that Spring MVC will inject for you and then use the [HttpServletRequest#isUserInRole(String)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#servletapi-user-in-role).

Also assuming you have mapped your view as below:

- "**indexAdmin**" -> "/your/static/resource/indexAdmin.html"
- "**indexUser**" -> "/your/static/resource/indexUser.html"
- "**indexProfesor**" -> "/your/static/resource/indexProfesor.html"

The method would look as below:

```
   @Controller
    public class HomeController {

       @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String loginPage(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, Model model) {
            if(httpServletRequest.isUserInRole("ADMIN")) {
                return "indexAdmin";
            } else if(httpServletRequest.isUserInRole("USER")) {
                return "indexUser";
            } else {
                return "indexProfesor";
            }
        }
    }
```

As mentioned in the Spring Documentation link above:

> [..]Typically users should not pass in the "ROLE_" prefix into this
>   method[..]

Comment: thanks for your comment. I think I need to make separate controller with mapping for example "/successLogin" and then put logic that you wrote above in it. If I put it like this with mapping "/login" it never takes me to my login page. Do you have any idea of how to do that?