# Not able to recognize user ROLE when redirecting page using Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am working on my project with Spring security and Thymeleaf. I have basic Spring Security integration.

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
      public void configureGlobal (AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
      {
        auth
          .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource);
      }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/success", true)
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
      } 
}
```

**SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java**

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer
{
    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer(){
        super(SecurityConfig.class);
    }

}
```

**Controller.java**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage(Model model) {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/success")
    public String loginPageRedirect(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest){

        if(httpServletRequest.isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            return "index1";
        } else if(httpServletRequest.isUserInRole("ROLE_USER")) {
            return "index2";
        } else {
            return "index3";
        }
    }
}
```

When I have successful login my user is redirected, but to wrong page. My user has role ROLE_USER but method *loginPageRedirect* is redirecting him to page index3 when it should be index2. I guess my user role is not recognize. How can I do that? Should I add something as parameter to *loginPageRedirect* so it recognizes role?

Comment: Would you please check : Adding a parameter `Authentication authentication`  in `/success` controller method, spring mvc will automatically inject authentication into that. And inside this method print all ` authentication.getAuthorities()`, and see whether the role is correct or not

Comment: @sunkuet02 Yes it display role [ROLE_USER] like this. But I still have wrong redirection.

Comment: try adding `httpServletRequest.authenticate(response);` at the very beginning of `loginPageRedirect` method. Add add an extra parameter `HttpServletResponse response` with this controller

Comment: @sunkuet02 what do you mean? Can you please write code so I can have it more clearly?

Comment: adding `httpServletRequest.authenticate(response);` at the very beginning of `loginPageRedirect` method. Add add an extra parameter `HttpServletResponse response` with this controller

Comment: Check it : http://paste.ubuntu.com/25325185/

Comment: If not work, then I think you have problems in your configurations . You can follow the second way of that link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45709721/2315473

Comment: I found solution :) look at answer! Thanks for you comments! :) @sunkuet02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution that works for me.

I edited my *loginPageRedirect* method like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/success")
    public void loginPageRedirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String role =  authResult.getAuthorities().toString();

        if(role.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")){
         response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(request.getContextPath() + "/index1"));                            
         }
         else if(role.contains("ROLE_USER")) {
             response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(request.getContextPath() + "/index2"));
         }
    }
```

Hope it helps someone with same issue :)

Comment: +1 Looks good. `Authentication` helps it afterall. Then you can review my last answer on your privious question

Comment: @sunkuet02 Thank you mate! :) I also posted a full answer on that question have a look.